# How to overwrite an element in javascript object array

Tags: javascript, debugging, variables, object, syntax

I want to do the following in javascript but there's something about the syntax I'm not understanding here:

```
var theObj = { foo: val1, bar: val2 }
if ( condition ) {
  theObj[foo] = newVal
  return theObj // returns { foo: val1, bar: newVal } 
}
return theObj // returns { foo: val1, bar: val2 }
```

Comment: I know there was a syntax error there, whoops, got it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is not an *object array*, but rather an *object literal*. Normally, its properties would be accessed as `theObj.property`, but JavaScript provides an alternative syntax of `theObj["property"]` when you need to do operations like string manipulation on the property name (like `theObj["property_" + numberVar]`), or for properties not valid in dot notation (like number properties `theObj[12] = "twelve"`)

If you access the property via `[]`, you would need to quote the string `["foo"]`, otherwise the parser would be looking for a variable named `foo` to insert there. However, this simple string property is better accessed with dot notation:

```
if ( condition ) {
  theObj.foo = newVal
  return theObj // returns { foo: val1, bar: newVal } 
}
```

Comment: Bracket access is also needed when what would otherwise be invalid dot access syntax: `var obj = {1e5: 3}; alert(obj[1e5])`